# Transposing data frame based on date and factor column in R

Tags: r

I have a table like that:

| date | device | v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan-22 | mobile | 1 | 11 |
| jan-22 | pc | 2 | 12 |
| may-22 | mobile | 3 | 13 |
| may-22 | pc | 4 | 14 |

and I would like something like that:

|  |  | jan-22 | may-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **mobile** |  |  |  |
|  | **v1** | 1 | 3 |
|  | **v2** | 11 | 13 |
| **pc** |  |  |  |
|  | **v1** | 2 | 4 |
|  | **v2** | 12 | 14 |

Comment: it is not necessarily a dataframe, it can be a list like xtabs ()

Answer (score 1):

```
ftable(xtabs(v~device+time+date, reshape(df, -(1:2), idvar = 1:2, sep='', dir='long')))
            date jan-22 may-22
device time                   
mobile 1              1      3
       2             11     13
pc     1              2      4
       2             12     14
```

or even:

```
ftable(xtabs(values~.,cbind(df[1:2], stack(df[3:4]))), row.vars = 2:3)

         date jan-22 may-22
device ind                   
mobile v1            1      3
       v2           11     13
pc     v1            2      4
       v2           12     14
```

which is:

```
ftable(xtabs(values~.,cbind(df[1:2], stack(df[3:4]))), row.vars = c('device', 'ind'))
```

or even:

```
ftable(xtabs(values~device+ind+date,cbind(df[1:2], stack(df[3:4]))))
           date jan-22 may-22
device ind                   
mobile v1            1      3
       v2           11     13
pc     v1            2      4
       v2           12     14
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested solution for reference.

```
df=data.frame( date =c("jan-22", "jan-22", "may-22","may-22"),
            device=c("mobile","pc","mobile","pc"), 
             v1=c(1,12,3,4), v2=c(11,12,13,14))

library(tidyr)
a1=spread(df[,c(1,2,3)], key = date, value = v1)
a1$type='v1'
a2=spread(df[,c(1,2,4)], key = date, value = v2)
a2$type='v2'

a=rbind(a1, a2)
a=a[, c(1,4,2,3)]
a[order(a$device,a$type), ]
```

The answer will look like below

```
    device  type    jan-22  may-22
    <fct>   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   mobile  v1  1   3
3   mobile  v2  11  13
2   pc  v1  12  4
4   pc  v2  12  14
```